# Just replaced my whole house water filtration system/, now I have NO hot water in shower or my kitchen sink, but DO have hot water in bathroom sink

Tags: hot-water

I recently replaced my electric hot water heater.All faucets and shower had been working perfectly until yesterday when I replaced my whole house water filtration system, and immediately after that until now I have NO HOT water in my kitchen sink or shower, very strange, cause I STILL do HAVE HOT water in my bathroom sink only!

Comment: No hot water or no water from the hot tap?  Might have blockage somewhere from loosening stuff in the plumbing.  Check that shut off valves are turned on.

Comment: Did you replace the filter or the entire filter system?

Comment: Air in the system

Comment: Sounds like the bathroom sink is first on the path, then shower and kitchen.  So a blockage between the bathroom sink and shower, so hopefully a short distance to check.

Comment: Re Ruskes suggestion: How long did you leave the valve open before concluding nothing was happening? Air in the pipes is certain possible, but should flush itself out reasonably quickly.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the filtration system? Make sure to be far enough away to show how the water lines run into and out of it. As of now, it's anyone's guess and my guess is that you plumbed something wrong or touched more plumbing than you've presented in your question.